# Work, Energy, Kinematics Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics

A heavy frog and a light frog jump straight into the air. Both have the same kinetic energy just as they leave the ground. Air resistance is negligible. Which of these statements about these frogs are correct?

The answer was both frogs reach the same maximum height, and just as they leave the ground, the lighter frog is moving faster.

I do not understand the first statement. If the lighter frog has a greater velocity, should it not reach a greater height?

Comment: You are right. It should definitely reach a greater height.

Answer (score 1):

If air resistance is negligible then I assume that energy is conserved. Then you can equal the initial and final energy for each frog $$ E_\text{heavy frog} = E_\text{light frog} $$ 
At the highest point all the energy is potential (I am assuming they have jumped vertically) so $E_i = m_i g h_i$ where $m_i$ is the mass of each frog and $h_i$ is the height it reaches. Thus

$$ m_\text{heavy frog} g h_\text{heavy frog} = m_\text{light frog} g h_\text{light frog} $$

or, canceling the $g$'s and rearanging,

$$ h_\text{heay frog} = \frac{m_\text{light frog}}{m_\text{heavy frog}} h_\text{light_frog} $$

so it is clear that $h_\text{heavy frog} < h_\text{light frog}$.